# Enable the Show Formulas in Excel from C# code

Tags: c#, excel, excel-automation

I am creating a windows application in C# .net to open an excel sheet and edit it. I am using excel automation in c# to do this.After editing/modifying some values in the sheet I will save the entire sheet in text file format. I am editing only one sheet and the sheet I am editing have formulas that have dependency on other sheet. So the formulas in the sheet are coming as #NAME?. When I save this excel sheet in .txt format I am getting the same error code instead of the formulas. I want the real formulas in my sheet and the text file.

Excel have an option to show the real formulas with the Formulas->Show Formulas.

I want the same to be done using the excel automation in c#

any suggestions

Comment: Please provide detail description your question with efforts done by you for that. Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you are looking for is [`DisplayFormulas`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff193245.aspx) on the [`Window`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835196.aspx) object. For example:

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = True
```

Comment: This code is for VBA right?. I am searching for the same in C#. Thank you